# Forge override main menu

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm having to change the main menu of Minecraft using Minecraft Forge. I managed to change the base code to copy a save file to the Saves folder and then load that save. But when I compile it it doesn't work. I'm guessing it's because its a baseclass that I have edited and it doesn't get included in the compile. I do also understand that I should not edit the baseclasses, but it won't interfere with anything so it should be OK.
Is there anyway to compile the baseclasses that has been edited, or maybe another way of editing the main menu. I've read about interrupting the load of the GUI and replace it with my own, but I haven't found any good way of doing that.

Below is the code, slightly stripped down: **net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiMainMenu.java**

```
private void addSingleplayerMultiplayerButtons(int p_73969_1_, int p_73969_2_)
{
    this.buttonList.add(new GuiButton(15, this.width / 2 - 100, p_73969_1_, I18n.format("Quickplay", new Object[0])));
}

protected void actionPerformed(GuiButton p_146284_1_)
{
    if (p_146284_1_.id == 15)
    {
        // Clone and create new map
        File srcFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\quickMap");
        File destFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\saves\\tempQuickMap");

        //make sure source exists
        if(!srcFolder.exists()){

           //System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
           //just exit
           //System.exit(0);

        }else{

           try{
            copyFolder(srcFolder,destFolder);
           }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //error, just exit
                //System.exit(0);
           }
        }

        //System.out.println("Done");
        // Cloning done

        if (this.mc.getSaveLoader().canLoadWorld("tempQuickMap"))
        {
            FMLClientHandler.instance().tryLoadExistingWorldMainMenu(this, "tempQuickMap", "Quickplay map");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Don't edit things starting with `net.minecraft.*` or `net.minecraftforge.*`! Use ASM instead!

Comment: I am in 1.7.x and I don't think I can use ASM with that version. It's that API for "editing base classes without editing base classes", ey?
However, none of the other mods I'll be using will interfere with base class editing, so that'd be no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASM in 1.7.x, but it is complicated and unnecessary for your purpose.
Subscribe to the GuiOpenEvent, check whether the gui is the main menu and if so call the event.setGui method to set it to your GUI instead.